# Backup and migrate backs up previous backup

Tags: migrations, backups

The backup and migrate when backing up my drupal site adds the previous backup to it which makes the backup twice the size of the original backup. How do I solve this as my backups keeps increasing in size?

Comment: I don't know this module, are you able to set where the backup is stored? If so, obviously you'll need to store it outside of your Drupal directory.

Comment: This module backs up database to disk. So how could it backup old backup? It's already on disk, not in database.

Comment: I think I will try your option @Darvanen. I am talking about entire drupal file+Dbase but not Dbase only.